# Number of bytes allocated to an array after it's declaration in java

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, how the check number of bytes allocated to an array after it's declaration? 
For example:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
```

Array 'a' is allocated 4*10 bytes since the size of int is 4 bytes and there are 10 integer elements. Is there a non-manual way of doing this?

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object).

Answer (score 1):

In Java there is no operator like `sizeof` in C to get the size of the array element. So there is at least no straightforward way.

By the way, no memory is allocated during declaration, only during initialization.

Declaration:

```
int[] a;
```

Initialization:

```
a = new int[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the size of `int[10]` is 56 bytes or more (depending on your JVM).

- 10 * 4 = 40 bytes for the ten ints
- 4 bytes to store the array length
- 8 bytes for the Java object
- 4 bytes to make the size of the object a multiple of 8 (alignment).

But this all depends on the JVM and memory architecture of your operating system. `java.lang.instrumentation.Instrumentation` provides a way to calculate sizes of an object, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682/3215527).